# extend an object with hidden properties

Tags: class, properties, coffeescript

I have the following coffeescript class

```
class Data
  constructor: (data)->
    data.prototype.meta = @meta
    return data
  meta: ->
    return { id: 123 }

# this is how I want to work with it, as an example
a = {name: "val"}
x = new Data a

for key, item of x
   console.log key, item ## should say `name`, `val` (not meta)

console.log x.meta ## should say `{id:123}
```

I would like to add the `meta` property to an existing `object`, but I do **NOT** want the `meta` to come up when I loop on the new object `x` using a for loop.

If I have failed to explain this properly please let me know I will try and do better :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Object.defineProperty()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty):

```
class Data
  constructor: (data) ->
    Object.defineProperty(data, "meta", { enumerable: false, value: @meta });
    return data
  meta: { id: 123 }

a = {name: "val"}
x = new Data(a)

for key, item of x
   console.log key, item ## should say `name`, `val` (not meta)

console.log x.meta ## should say `{id:123}
```

Answer (score 0):

A ended up using the following...

```
a = {name: "val"}
a.meta = {id: 123} ## as normal
Object.defineProperty a, "meta", enumerable: false ## this hides it from loops


for key, item of x
   console.log key, item ## should say `name`, `val` (not meta)

console.log x.meta ## should say `{id:123}
```